# Why does this equality between expectations hold?

Tags: probability

Why does this equality between expectations hold (second equality)?

[image]

Comment: Linearity of expectation combined with $\mathbb E(X_iX_j)=\mathbb E(X_jX_i)$ in this context for $i\neq j$

Comment: @drhab Could you please expand on that? I don't see at all where it comes from still.

Comment: Do you understand the first part of the answer of @V.C.? Do you agree that $(a_1+a_2)^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_2a_1$?

Comment: @drhab Ah ok, that makes sense. I didn't realize how that would look in sum notation. Could you explain to me however how to get the indices for the double sum (second term)?

Comment: Is $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_ia_j$ clear to you?

Comment: @drhab Yes, but then how does that give these indices?

Comment: Seeing your comment on V.C. I reckon you are helped now. Cheers.

Comment: @drhab Yes he did, thank you very much for your help though :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
\biggl[\sum_{i=1}^na_i\biggr]^2=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2+2\sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_ia_j
$$
for real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and
$$
\operatorname E\biggl[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\biggr]=\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname EX_k
$$
for random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me why this holds for all real numbers?

Comment: @aawerawer Intuitively, it is easy to understand this formula for small $n$. Take, for example, $n=3$. Then we have that $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac$. [Here](http://planetmath.org/squareofsum) you can find a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't recognize the identity in sum notation. Could you please tell me how I can see that the indices for the double sum are correct?

Comment: @aawerawer We need to sum all the double products of the summands. We have that $$\sum_{i=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_ia_j=a_2a_1+a_3(a_1+a_2)+a_4(a_1+a_2+a_3)+\ldots+a_n(a_1+\ldots+a_{n-1}).$$

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks for your help :)!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\right)^2 & = (r_1+\cdots+r_n)(r_1+\cdots+r_n)
\\[0ex]\tag{2} & = r_1(r_1+\cdots+r_n)+r_2(r_1+\cdots+r_n)+\cdots+r_n(r_1+\cdots+r_n)
\\[2ex]\tag{3} & = (r_1^2 +\cdots+r_n^2) +r_1(r_2+\cdots+ r_n)+r_2(r_1+r_3+\cdots+r_n)+\cdots+r_n(r_1+\cdots+r_{n-1})
\\[2ex]\tag{4} & = (r_1^2 +\cdots+r_n^2) + 2r_1(r_2+\cdots+ r_n)+2r_2(r_3+\cdots+r_n)+\cdots+2r_{n-1}r_n
\\[1ex]\tag{5} & = \sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2) + 2r_1(r_2+\cdots+ r_n)+2r_2(r_3+\cdots+r_n)+\cdots+2r_{n-1}r_n
\\[1ex]\tag{6} & = \sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2) + 2r_1\sum_{j=2}^n (r_j)+2r_2\sum_{j=3}^n (r_j)+\cdots+2r_{n-1}\sum_{j=n}^n (r_j)
\\[1ex]\tag{7} & = \sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(r_i\sum_{j=i+1}^n (r_j)\right)
\\[1ex]\tag{8} & = \sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (r_i r_j)
\\[3ex]\tag{9} \mathsf E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\right)^2\right] & = \mathsf E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (r_i r_j)\right]
\\[1ex]\tag{10} & = \mathsf E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i^2)\right] + 2 \mathsf E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (r_i r_j)\right]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry but I think the index of your second sum in the double sum is not correct ($n$ should be $i$). But thanks a lot for the extensive clarification!